# How is the value of Standard gravitational parameter for Earth derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

Its been a while since I've done any physics, I'm working on some orbital programs. I'm using this formula

$\mu = MG$

where $M$ is the mass of the body and $G$ is the gravitational constant.

The value that I find for earth is $398600$ or so

However $G$ is defined with $10^{-11}$ exponent and the mass of the earth is defined as $5$ with a $10^{24}$ exponent. The units of kilograms are same but it seems like it should have 13 decimal places, not 5.

What am I missing?

Comment: sorry, the Greek mu is the way I've seen it referenced. It could be double ghgh = Mass * GravitationalContant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to be careful with the units.  On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) which gives the gravitational parameter of the Earth as $398,600$, the units are km$^3$s$^{-2}$, so this is $3.986E14$ m$^3$s$^{-2}$ in agreement with your figures for $G$ and the mass of the earth in SI units.

Comment: Thank you, I was focused on the kg unit and missed the conversion of meters to kilometers.